# How to grasp a cup by PR2 on simulations?

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run some complicated scenarios on simulations,such as pr2 grasp a cup or similar scenarios.

Where can I start?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12593/how-to-grasp-a-cup-by-pr2-on-simulations?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric, you can use pr2_interactive_manipulation: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_interactive_manipulation .
Use 'roslaunch pr2_interactive_manipulation pr2_manipulation_gazebo.launch' to start a sim of a robot with a can on a table in front of it.
Then run 'roslaunch pr2_interactive_manipulation pr2_interactive_manipulation_robot.launch stereo:=true' to start up all the manipulation stacks and such, and 'roslaunch pr2_interactive_manipulation pr2_interactive_manipulation_desktop.launch stereo:=true' to start rviz with relevant topics and such.

The documentation on how to use it is a bit out of date; look at this wiki page for a more up-to-date description: http://www.ros.org/wiki/robhum/grasping

For coding your own autonomous stuff, look at
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application
for C++
and http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials/A%20Simple%20Pick%20And%20Place%20Example%20Using%20The%20Pick%20And%20Place%20Manager
for python.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-04-02**:
Did the pr2_manipulation_gazebo.launch file move? It doesn't appear to be in pr2_interactive_manipulation anymore. I'm running electric. https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/branches/0.5-branch/applications/pr2_interactive_manipulation/launch/

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-04-02**:
Nevermind. Found it in trunk. https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/trunk/applications/pr2_interactive_manipulation/launch/

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2012-04-03**:
oops, didn't comment in the right place.  See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ergh.  You probably shouldn't be using trunk right now--trunk is now trying to be Fuerte-compatible, except a lot of stuff is not working yet.

That launch has been moved to the package manipulation_worlds, which now has a whole selection of interesting worlds for manipulating stuff in Gazebo in Electric:
https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/branches/0.5-branch/applications/manipulation_worlds
pr2_table_object.launch is equivalent to the old pr2_manipulation_gazebo.launch.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1